# How to add comments to .env file?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I am using `dotenv` module to load environment variables from `.env` file.

`.env`:

```
# config
DAILY_REPORT_SCHEDULE='*/1 * * * *'
PORT=8080
NODE_ENV=development
DOTENV_DEBUG=true

# credentials
PROJECT_ID=shadowsocks-218808
KEY_FILE_NAME='/Users/ldu020/workspace/nodejs-gcp/.gcp/shadowsocks-218808-7f8e109f4089.json'
```

As you can see, I add two comments within `.env` file.

`dotenv.js`:

`require('dotenv').config({ debug: process.env.DOTENV_DEBUG === 'true' });`

`dotenv` give me debug messages:

```sh
[dotenv][DEBUG] did not match key and value when parsing line 1: # config
[dotenv][DEBUG] did not match key and value when parsing line 6:
[dotenv][DEBUG] did not match key and value when parsing line 7: # credentials
[dotenv][DEBUG] did not match key and value when parsing line 10:
[dotenv][DEBUG] did not match key and value when parsing line 11:
```

I know the reason why got these debug messages is I added two comments and some new line within `.env` file. `dotenv` does not parse `.env` file correctly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: From [the source code](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js) you can see that there is no support for comments or even blank lines.

Comment: Don't use comments. Can't u use GROUP=config? Or NOTGOINGTOUSETHISKEY = credentials?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Since 2022 both separate line comments and inline comments are supported.

Line started with `#` symbol is a separate line comment. See [the docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#rules). Inlined `#` sign denotes the start of an [inline comment](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#comments) (thanks to @reddisht to note this in comments).

For [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#comments) the same situation.

Here is the example for both:

```bash
# This is the separate comment line
NODE_ENV=stage
APP_VERSION=1.0.0 # This is an inline comment
```

The `"#"` (double quote wrapped hash symbol) is not treated as a comment even at line beginning starting from v15.0.0 (thanks to @walkingbrad commented this below).

There are parsing peculiarities you may find good to know described in  [this](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#what-rules-does-the-parsing-engine-follow) docs section.

Yet do not forget that some packages like e.g. [mrsteele/dotenv-webpack](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) (at least v7.1.1) do not support inline comments and you can face your application's unexpected behaviour putting inline comments in your `.env` files.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, `dotenv` module support comment

Comment: Good to be aware that `dotenv` doesn't support inline comments

Comment: It appears that as of v14.3.2, `motdotla/dotenv` does now support inline comments.

Comment: Also be aware of:
>Comments begin where a # exists, so if your value contains a # please wrap it in quotes. This is a breaking change from >= v15.0.0 and on.

Comment: `next.js` also doesn't support inline comments.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2022-04-17, both comment lines and inline comments are available.
Just use `#`.

Shamelessly copied from https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#comments:

```
# Comment
SECRET_KEY=YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE # Comment
SECRET_HASH="something-with-a-#-hash"
```

Answer (score 4):

As of 13 Aug 2022 7:20 am UTC (Because Node, Angular, javascript etc. keep changing often) this is the status:

You can use `#` for comments.

```
# MY_TEMPORARY_VARIABLE = 'Some value'
```

But remember, this feature is still in primitive stage as it will not accept comment in same line. Thus:

```
MY_TEMPORARY_VARIABLE = 'Some value' # This is comment
```

In this case

```
let myVar = process.env.MY_TEMPORARY_VARIABLE;
```

`myVar` will hold value:

```
'Some value # This is comment'
```

You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> You can add a comment in .env by starting a line with a hash (#)
> symbol. E.g.

```
# host value
DB_HOST=host
# username
DB_USER=admin
# secure password
DB_PASS=pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything written in the same code line right of # or ; is comments.